# MS SQL Reporting Services on azure

Tags: macos, sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database

Please correct me if I am wrong. Since Azure is a  cloud service. Can  I create  azure account and  learn SQL server reporting in there? I am a mac  user and do not want to install a VM neither install windows on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft used to provide SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) as a service in the past, but this has been deprecated. See [here](http://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2013/11/windows-azure-sql-reporting-discontinued/).

The only way is for you to spin a VM in Azure, and install SSRS in it. Now bear in mind that spinning a SQL Server VM might result in costs way higher than you might expect (due to licenses), so always make sure you run it on a version of SQL Server Developer, which has all the features of the highest SQL edition, but it is free (not to be run in production). See [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-sql-server-2016-developer-image-in-the-azure-gallery/).